# Group and child divider in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

Hi I want to have divider between group row but not between child rows. I'm using:

```
android:divider="#A8A8A8"
android:dividerHeight="5.0sp"
```

to get space between group rows but what about children? I was trying with `android:childDivider="@null"` and `android:childDivider="#00000000"` but it doesn't work properly. I was also using View element inside group layout but I dont think it's pretty solution. And what if I want to have different divider in children than in group, I mean different height and color? Is it possible to do without View element in layout?
If there is no other possibility I can use View element in group row but where should I hide it after expand listview and then show it?

Answer (score 0):

So I've decided to do it using View element but sometimes it doesn't dissapear without no reason. I though it might by Threads issue but I tried run on Ui Thread and it didnt help. This is my code, also I'm using AnimatedExpandableListView https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView:

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, final View v, final int groupPosition, long id) {
    Boolean shouldExpand = (!expandableListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition));
    if (shouldExpand) {
      if (currentlyExpanded != -1) {
        expandableListView.collapseGroup(currentlyExpanded);
        View view = getViewByPosition(currentlyExpanded, expandableListView).findViewById(R.id.dummyView);
        if (view != null) {
          view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
      }
      expandableListView.expandGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
      smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(expandableListView, groupPosition);
      v.findViewById(R.id.dummyView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      currentlyExpanded = groupPosition;
      return true;
    }
    v.findViewById(R.id.dummyView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return false;
  }
});
```